# ng-repeat is not updating when local storage node got deleted

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Angularjs `ng-repeat` is not updating when i delete the whole local storage node

i used `$scope.$apply();` but its not working

**ng-repeat div**

```
<div class="col-xs-3 well">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-ng-click="dellocal()"><i class=" glyphicon glyphicon-remove-sign"></i></button>
<ul class="list-group">
<li class="list-group-item" data-ng-repeat="item in del" >
id:{{ item.id }}
<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-ng-click="delItem_fr_delete(item);"><i class=" glyphicon glyphicon-remove-sign"></i></button>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

**and my delete function**

```
 $scope.dellocal = function (item) 
 {
  delete $localStorage.fr_delete;
 }
```

**[my plunker demo](http://embed.plnkr.co/LbB1SuzZC6JqPBWAcXyZ/preview)**

Comment: You don't seem to have told us what `del` is or how it has anything to do with `$localStorage.fr_delete`.

Comment: not to mention why you have `item` argument and don't use it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are copying $localStorage.fr_delete into another variable on scope called $scope.del.

Deleting $localStorage.fr_delete will not delete $scope.del which is bound in your view through controller.

Update your method like this :

```
 $scope.dellocal = function (item) {
       delete $localStorage.fr_delete;
       $scope.del = [];
    }
```